# Spark mapWithState updated states output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

After upgrading to Spark 1.6.1, I've started refactoring an application to replace `updateStateByKey` with `mapWithState`.

In order to take advantage of the performance advantages of the new API, I don't want to call `stateSnapshots`, which loads all states. I only want the updated states.

The `mapWithState` API returns a `DStream` of `[key, input, state, output]`, where each state is the partially updated state after an input is ingested. How can I extract the latest states alone from this `DStream` (i.e. the state after all corresponding inputs have been ingested / mapped)?

I can do a `map` (to drop the input and output) and `reduceByKey` on the `MapWithStateDStream`, choosing the state with the newer timestamp (which I set inside the update function), but I have no guarantee there won't be two partial states with the same timestamp, even if using a custom, by key, partitioner.

How can I tell which partial state is the latest in the `MapWithStateDStream` output of `mapWithState`?

Answer (score 3):

`mapWithState` will only be called for each state which is being updated in the current micro batch. One way to achieve what you want is to return an `Some[S]` in case the state has been updated.

`StateSpec.function` takes a method with the following signature:

```
mappingFunction: 
    (Time, KeyType, Option[ValueType], State[StateType]) => Option[MappedType]
```

What we can do is make sure that our `Option[MappedType]` is always `Some[MappedType]` when the value has been updated, otherwise `None`.

For example:

```
def updateState(key: Int, value: Option[Int], state: State[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    value match {
      case Some(something) if something > 10 =>
        val updatedVal = something * something
        state.update(updatedVal)
        Some(updatedVal)
      case _ => None
    }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
val spec = StateSpec.function(updateState _)
ssc.mapWithState(spec).filter(!_.isEmpty).foreachRDD(/* do stuff on updated state */)
```

This way you filter out any none updated state and keep only the updated snapshots you're looking for.

Comment: The state is always updated - every input action updates the state, so I always return a `Some(updatedState)`. This means the output contains all partial states, I just want the one after all related actions have been processed. I think I should have mentioned that there are multiple actions corresponding to the same key. `mapWithState` is called for every action, not every state. It can be called multiple times for the same state.

Comment: @Seppeh Can you post a [MCVE] of your code? Especially your Spark DAG. Even though there a multiple actions to the same key, as long as you update the `State[S]` there no need to output the value like in `updateStateByKey`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that would work if it is possible for your update algorithm is to call reduceByKey on the input stream before calling mapWithstate. Then there would only be a single update for each key and no partial states output.